# Тип переменной во время компиляции или выполнения?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста:
почему в данной случае тип переменных `i`, `j` известен на этапе компиляции

```
template <int i, int j, class T>
auto to_pair(T tuple) -> decltype(std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple)))
{
    return std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple));
}
```

а здесь на этапе выполнения

```
template <class T>
auto to_pair(int i, int j, T tuple) -> decltype(std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple),
                                                               std::get<j>(tuple)))
{
    return std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple));
}
```

Ну или может поделитесь ссылкой, где поподробнее про это написано.

Comment: Написаное неверно. Тип i и j в обоих случаях - int - известен на стадии компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, вы путаете **тип** и **значение**.

Типы `i` и `j` известны во время компиляции - это `int`.

А вот значения во второй функции действительно могут быть известны только во время выполнения. Поэтому этот шаблон и не работает - `get` требуется знать *значение* индекса во время компиляции.